# Is this a good use-case of "mutable" in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, mutable

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    mutable int* m_buffer;
public:
    MyClass(void)
      : m_buffer(nullptr)
    {
    }
    void init(void)
    {
        m_buffer = new int[10];
    }
    // This is the only public interface to retrieve m_buffer
    const int* evaluate(int param) const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            m_buffer[i] = param*10;
        return m_buffer;
    }
};
```

I've read that `mutable` class members should be used when their state does not affect the class external state. In the above code the member `m_buffer` is retrieved only through the `evaluate()` method. This method will change the values of `m_buffer` but the new values depend only on the `param` argument. Is the use of the `mutable` keyword correct in this particular example?

I could avoid using `mutable` by:

- Allocating a new buffer every time I call the function. However, this will make my code slow because the buffer is usually a few gigabytes.
- Allocating the output buffer in advance and pass it as an argument to the `evaluate` function. However, this will make my API more hard to understand/use.
- Declaring `m_buffer` as `int* const`. However, this won't work because, due to a design decision, I can not allocate `m_buffer` in the constructor's initializer list.

Comment: Who is responsible for calling `delete` on `m_buffer`? Or in other words, who *owns* `m_buffer`?

Comment: Whoever made that "design decision" about having the initialization in a `init` member function thinks he/she is working with C.

Comment: I think conceptually `evaluate` *does* affect the class external state. `evaluate` effectively exposes the internal `m_buffer` externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the code you showed, you don't need to use [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) keyword at all.

In a const member function, the `this` pointer is const-qualified, then the members will be const too, for `m_buffer` it will be `int* const` (note it's not `const int*`), it means you still could change the values pointed by `m_buffer`, but not itself.

And in `evaluate()` you're only changing the valus `m_buffer` points to, not `m_buffer` itself, so it should be fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I don't know what was I thinking! Apologies for the silly question and thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that this is not really good idea when user can define such scenario:

```
MyClass evaluator;
const int* arrResult1 = evaluator.evaluate(10);
//use of arrResult1 
const int* arrResult2 = evaluator.evaluate(15);
//use of arrResult1 and arrResult2
```

In that case arrResult1 will be spoiled by calling `evaluate()` for second time.

You can change it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int* m_resultCache;
public:
    MyClass(void)
      : m_resultCache(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~MyClass() { delete[] m_resultCache; }

    const int* getResult() const { return m_resultCache; }

    void evaluate(int param)
    {
        if (m_resultCache == nullptr)
           m_resultCache = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            m_resultCache[i] = param*10;
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. The OP wants `evaluate` to be `const`.

Comment: @Henrik you'r right! I just wanted to point that such design could cause problems.